# editing JSON decoded key value using php

Tags: php

as the title says I want to edit a specific key-value within JSON decoded array, the array is stored in a table called `bills` under the `items` column so I tried to get the `items` array then decoded to be ready for editing inside a loop which detects the giving `key-value`.

what I tried so far

```
<?php

public function AlterJSON($billingID,$item,$key,$newValue){
    if($this->connected === true){
        try{
            $ColumnJ = $this->connection->prepare("SELECT `items` FROM `bills` WHERE id=:id");
            $ColumnJ->bindParam(":id",$billingID);
            $ColumnJ->execute();
            $fetched = $ColumnJ->fetchColumn();
            $decoded = json_decode($fetched);
            foreach($decoded as $product){
                if($product->$key == $item){

                    // if the value equals to the specific item then replace it with 
                    // $newValue after that i want to update the `items` column how to accomplish this?
                }
            }
        }
        catch(PDOException $e){
            if($this->errors === true){
                return $this->error($e->getMessage());
            }else{
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Update:- Column `items` datatype is [ json ] format:-

```
[
    {"0": "1", 
    "1": "o4", 
    "2": "fsdfds", 
    "3": "Eklil", 
    "4": "1", 
    "5": "30", 
    "6": "15", 
    "7": "Phezer", 
    "8": "Venlafaxine", 
    "9": "", 
    "10": "0", 
    "11": "2020-03-25", 
    "12": "2021-08-25", 
    "13": "1", 
    "14": "0", 
    "15": "0", 
    "16": "caps", 
    "17": "..\\upload\\Efexor.jpg"
]
```

Comment: Too Obscure: Please, give us a clue what data in the  `items` column looks like

Comment: @RiggsFolly updated the post

Comment: Dont think that JSON is valid

Comment: @RiggsFolly you mean this is not a json,right?

Comment: @RiggsFolly btw, as you can see i use json_decode first

Comment: But `json_decode()` can fail very quitely although you can check for errors `if ( json_last_error() >1){ echo json_last_error_msg(); }`